# Why does the program wait for all the inputs before printing each number?

Tags: c

This is the simple c code to print the number

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num == -1) {
            break; // Exit loop when -1 is encountered
        }

        printf("%d \n", num);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

here is how it looks like in the terminal

[image]

I have a question about why the program doesn't print the number immediately upon input and instead waits for all inputs before printing. I'm also curious about the distinction between entering a space and hitting the Enter key.

Comment: While this is in no way an authoritative answer, the likeliest culprit I would think of is that stdin is buffered, and so you are not reading any symbols (including EOF) until you've reached a newline. stdin is buffered for non-interactive inputs, but with a command-line terminal I'm not sure if that's the case. Behavior-wise, it's a bit odd to start acting on input before an <enter>/newline is reached, as that's quite against what almost all shells in existence do.

Comment: The program doesn't receive *any* input until newline is pressed. And then, `scanf` doesn't care what kind of whitespace you are using. For example with `scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);` and you can type `1` `Enter` `2` `Enter` and the function acts just as if you typed `1 2` `Enter`.

Comment: Both comments are answers, even with explanation. I recommend to turn them into an answer posts yourself and accepting it.

Comment: (@Yunnosch I'm quite guilty of putting answers in comments, but letting others take the effort+time to flesh them out into answer posts that I can upvote myself for the effort).

Comment: @Rogue Good to know. I assumed so, among other things because your rep is already quite satisfying. Answers I consider better... but your choice. There are users who comment and then are unhappy if it gets turned into an answer.., For about 10 minutes after the comment I sometimes am among them, when I just realised it and am typing an answer myself.... Tricky. ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use the enter key to terminate scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75987142/why-do-we-use-the-enter-key-to-terminate-scanf)

Comment: "I have a question about why the program doesn't print the number immediately upon input" - **how should it know** that you have finished inputting the number?

Comment: **Never** use `scanf()` without checking its return value. Or, to put it differently: User enters something that's not a number, `num` does not get initialized and you run into undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get the observed behavior is standard input is line buffered by default when attached to a terminal and the terminal itself is line buffered.

Hence the first `scanf()` requests input from `stdin`, which causes a read request from the terminal that does not return until a newline is entered by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

`scanf()` then can read and convert the first number `3`, leaving  `4 5 -1\n` pending in the `stdin` buffer.

`scanf()` sets `num` to `3` and returns `1` to the `main` function, `printf()` outputs `3` and a newline,

The loop continues and a second `scanf()` call reads the number `4`, that gets printed...

The same for the next number `5`...

The final call to `scanf()` reads `-1`, which causes the loop to end with a `break` statement and the program to exit to the shell.

If you used the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar, the terminal would return sooner to `scanf()` and numbers would appear immediately after the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is hit.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the program wait for all the inputs before printing each number?

Under Windows it seems to works ok. But...

I see, for your code as `p.exe`

```
SO> echo -1 | p

SO> echo 1 -1 | p
1

SO> p
1
1
2
2
-1
```

But...

```
SO> echo a | p
0
0
0
0
0
```

And the program loops forever, since `scanf` will never read a `-1` and gets stuck forever with the `\n` you did not read.

**It is not safe. And it is your fault**. At least you should write

```
        int num = -1; // so it exits at text
```

#### what is wrong?

- At first, it is safe to initialize `num` to your exit condition so the program does not loop if the user types a letter by mistake as the first input
- understand that `scanf` was not written for keyboard free-form input: it is intended to consume tabular data, like giant *csv* files or tables.
- **test** always the return value of `scanf` before assuming anything about the (eventually) read value (s):  it is not an error to read nothing. It is expected, hence the name of the function: it is a scanner: **scan**  **f**ormatted input. `scanf` scans the input, skipping white space until it gets data for the specifiers in the mask. Then it returns a count of how many things it got. But you ignored.
- understand that your code must consume the `\n` that ended `scanf` or the next call will find the same `\n` and return `0` forever, with **all** variables in the argument left unchanged. Since your end condition is based upon a value that can never change your program can never end.

#### A safe way

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int res = scanf("%d", &num);
        int ch = fgetc(stdin); // read the expected '\n'
        if (res < 1) continue;    // read nothing
        if (num == -1) return 0; // game over
        printf("%d \n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Why is that?

- the `scanf` mask is `%d` so it can return `-1` for error, `0` for no data or `1` for finding an `int` on input. It includes funny situations like this input:

  ```
    Stack Overflow 1 2
  1
  2
  -1 Nothing Else Matters
  ```

Here's the code:

- scans `1` and print it, after skipping `Stack Overflow` and the space
- then `fgets` the space

  - `fgets` read a char from a stream and return it as an `int`.
  - `ch` here is `32` the code for space
- then it scans `2`
- then `fgets` the `\n` that ended the line

  - `ch` here is `10`, the code for `\n`
- then if `fgets` the `-1`

And the program ends. The remaining data at the input buffer is flushed by the operating system.

Note that the last `return` will never run.

Notes:

- sometimes the (buffering) behaviour of the output is not ok and there is a need to assure that the data is printed before proceeding. That is the use of

  ```
  fflush(stdout);
  ```
- `fflush` is defined only for output streams. It is common for students to use --- and to be teached to do that, as I saw --- that to correct some hypothetical `bug` in `scanf` one must call `fflush(stdin)` to clear the buffer. Well, there is no bug and this is not defined. Some compilers accepts it as an extension. Sure, there are calls to flush input buffers under Windows and Linux. Under Linux see `ioctl`, under Windows see the console input documentation to find about `FlushConsoleInputBuffer`
- under `Windows` if you want to go further in understanding how `stdin` buffering works you can call `PeekConsoleInput` and see what is in the console input buffer without reading, at any time
- the behaviour of `stdin` is programmable, so you can tailor it to a specific need, like disabling echo and/or buffering. See linux/MACOS raw console input for example, or the console guide on Windows MSDN

Comment: thank you for this in-depth explaination, can you please tell me what is the role of this line `int ch = fgetc(stdin);` as the variable `ch` is not used again

Comment: It is a placeholder so you can check on the debugger for the value as read. If you just discard the output you can not inspect there for the presence of a `\n` or what...